# Is the term "iptables" ambiguous?

Tags: iptables

From some reading I did as a newcomer, I understand that the term **iptables** isn't really that straight forward as it sounds ("a list of ip addresses"), and may resemble at least 3 different things in the Linux discourse:

1. The *iptables* Linux kernel module made of an information system in the form of context-based tables which acts as logical basis for another Linux kernel module - The *Linux firewall*.
2. A Linux utility also called *iptables* that comes virtually in any distro, and uses a sysadmin to manipulate the kernel module called *iptables* (section 1) by **commands**, "from outside" (instead by text editing, "from inside").
3. A potential set of tables (or a single table) inside the *iptables* kernel module, dealing with allowed or blocked IP addresses.

I am new to Linux and can't tell how exactly was I accurate here; My question is if this is accurate and if there aren't any more "semantic" names for these types of software.

Edit: It was also unclear to me if it is right to explain "iptables chain" just a "special type of rules" or as "a particular iptables command dealing with all cells in a row". I did saw we can change a row in a "chained" command, like `iptables [-arguments] [value per column]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's (1) and (2), and as they are closely related (the latter being an interface to the former), this is not really a reason for confusion.

And it's a set of *rules for handling IP packets, and the rules happen to be arranged in tables*, so "list of ip addresses" makes no sense at all. The previous implementation was called [ipchains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipchains), because the rules were arranged in a chain, so the name of the new implementation emphasized that there are now several tables of chains.

Comment: Upvoted, but you might still want to point out some misunderstandings and weirdneses in the OP's exposition of (1) and (2). It's unclear how a text file could be communicated from user space to kernel space if there wasn't a command which did this, for example.

Comment: Also, there isn't really any ambiguity here; the `iptables` system is a single thing, and if you want to talk about just the kernel module component or just the command-line tool, you use phrases like this if it's not otherwise clear from the context.

Comment: Is an "iptables chain" just a "special type of rules" or is it "all cells in a row". That wasn't clear to me as a newcomer, when I saw we can change a row in a "chained" command.

Comment: I very much enjoyed your explanation. I also had a question regarding iptables which I was wondering if you might know the reasoning behind: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359884/understanding-an-iptables-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

> Is an "iptables chain" just a "special type of rules" or is it "all cells in a row"?

iptables contain a number of chains.  By default, there are 3 chains, INPUT, OUTPUT and FORWARD. You can also add your own custom chains.  Each chain consists of zero or more rules. Rules are evaluated in the order they appear in a chain. You can add, modify, move or delete rules in a chain.  Rules consist of a pattern and an action.  Chains have a default action also.